DirectX 12 Recording The Front Buffer
I'm building an example DX12 application that utilizes FSR3 and DLSS3. Both of these techniques use frame generation, and as far as I can tell, the interpolated frame is presented in a separate swap chain. Therefore, real and interpolated frames are presented at different times and through different command lists.
For my application, I need to dump all of these frames (real and interpolated) to disk. I have the necessary methods to dump the swap chain render target and any ID3D12Resource. However, my application only calls the present function for real frames, so I don't have access to the interpolated frames.
I tried dumping the frame before and after the command list was executed in hopes of capturing the interpolated frame. However, I quickly realized that this approach is neither possible nor reliable. I ran the application through PIX and confirmed that there are two updates between two real frames, and I identified the names of those resources. This only applies to FSR3, though—I couldn’t run DLSS with PIX, but that’s a separate issue.
I'm trying to figure out a way to capture all of the presented frames in any way possible. I think one way to achieve this might be by patching the swap chain factory, but I’m hoping there’s a simpler solution.
EDIT: I don't need to view the frames as part of the application; I could render them to a different target, like a file, and post-process that file. I just don't know how or even if it's possible to do so.
